# GitHub Actions: do not run workflow concurrently

Tags: github-actions

I have a workflow that deploys the app on push to main. The problem is that it should not run concurrently. Oftentimes I have multiple small PRs merged (e.g. version bumps by Renovate) and concurrent runs of this workflow fail as the deployed version changes while the deploy is in progress.

Can I throttle the workflow to either wait for previous run to finish before starting or to wait some time before starting so it only runs once for multiple frequent pushes?

Comment: Yes? https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-jobs/using-concurrency#examples-using-concurrency-and-the-default-behavior

Comment: It would feel like just duplicating the authoritative source, the documentation, elsewhere. It's the top google hit for the exact question title, so it's not like it's unlikely to be found, either.