# CICD initating with dalay after a new commit

Tags: github, github-actions, cicd

I have a repository with CICD which after each new commit, it starts the CICD process.
I have some commits applying in my repo with the following order:

commit 4 - time: 14-Dec-2022 12:00:30 - CICD starts

commit 3 - time: 14-Dec-2022 12:00:20 - CICD starts

commit 2 - time: 14-Dec-2022 12:00:10 - CICD starts

commit 1 - time: 14-Dec-2022 12:00:00 - CICD starts

What I want to do is that I consider a buffer time in CICD initiation that if I have for example 5 commit in a minute, it just CICD the latest one instead of having all running and interfering with each other. Something like this:

commit 4 - time: 14-Dec-2022 12:00:30 - CICD starts

commit 3 - time: 14-Dec-2022 12:00:20 - CICD DOES NOT start

commit 2 - time: 14-Dec-2022 12:00:10 - CICD DOES NOT start

commit 1 - time: 14-Dec-2022 12:00:00 - CICD DOES NOT start

I can delay each CICD but that won't be helpful.

Even being able to cancel previous unfinished CICD workflows with the initiation of a new CICD would be helpful.

Comment: Why do they "interfere" with each other? *That's* the root problem you should be looking to address.

Comment: There's also [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/73545747/1079354) in which someone's provided an authoritative answer in the comments section.

Comment: @DanielMann I think deploying 2 different builds to the same target environment is a pretty common reason not to want them to run simultaneously?

Comment: @Makoto Using Concurrency solved my issue. Thanks!